# When the apache beam will be released as jar file to add as project dependcy in eclipse?

Tags: apache-beam

When the apache beam will be released?
Will it has feature to connect with oracle RDBMS to do ETL in its first release?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam has had two incubating [releases](http://beam.incubator.apache.org/use/releases/) so far, with the third currently underway. We release the source code to [dist.apache.org](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/incubator/beam/) and binary jars to [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.apache.beam).

We don't release an all-inclusive bundled jar. Instead, we recommend using a tool like Maven (mvn), or m2e plugin in Eclipse, or native support in IntelliJ to make all dependencies automatically managed for you.

The third release should include the [JdbcIO API](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc), which presumably should work well with Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks Davor, Any tentative date for third release?

Comment: If I want to run a program on my local jvm,which are the jar files that are needed? How to know which jar files are mandatory?

Comment: Does Beam support jdk6?

Comment: The week of 10/31 is the current ETA for the third release. No, Beam doesn't support Java 6 -- we require Java 7 or 8. You can run a pipeline locally using core SDK and DirectRunner; those artifacts will automatically pull in any required dependencies if you use Maven / m2e in Eclipse / IntelliJ or a similar tool.